# Particular Id at First

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Actually I have a car table as `CAR` it has 3 fields:

- `carId`.
- `carName`.
- `carPrice`.

Car table has 15 records,, I just want to have the 5th record at first rest of the records at any order as `DESC`, `ASC`.

My main aim is to have the particular `carId` at first all other records as `DESC` or `ASC` one by one!

I think I am clear to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause something like this:

```
SELECT carId ,carName,carPrice
FROM Car 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN carId = @th5thid THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Carid
```

Answer (score 2):

Although @Mahmoud answer works perfectly, a `case` in the `order by` can make it difficult for the engine to optimize the query. You can avoid it like this:

```
select carid, carname, carprice
from car 
order by carid != 5, carid
```

In mysql a comparison will return 0 or 1 hence no need to wrap it in a `case` statement:

```
mysql> select 1 = 0;
+-------+
| 1 = 0 |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+

mysql> select 1 = 1;
+-------+
| 1 = 1 |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```